# Was the Duchess of Mandalore named Satine as a reference to Moulin Rouge?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Satine Kryze, Duchess of Mandalore, was introduced in Star Wars:  The Clone Wars episode ["The Mandalore Plot"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mandalore_Plot).

It is revealed during the Mandalore storyline that Obi-Wan Kenobi had fallen in love with Satine while stationed on Mandalore as a Padawan with Qui-Gon Jinn.  Obi-Wan indicates that he would have given up the Jedi Order if she only [said the word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIFmRcT1aYw).

Ewan MacGregor, who played Ob-Wan Kenobi in Episodes 1, 2, and 3 (although he was not the voice actor during The Clone Wars), also played Christian, the writer and protagonast and love interest of Satine in the Baz Luhrmann movie "Moulin Rogue!".

Did the production team of Star Wars:  The Clone Wars name Obi-Wan's (apparent) only love as a reference to Satine in "Moulin Rouge!"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this site](http://duchessofkalevala.webs.com/behindthescenes.htm), SW:TCW supervising director Dave Filoni says it was complete coincidence. Although he admits that it's a pretty odd one.

> **On Moulin Rouge References**
>
> **Filoni:** *It was the funniest thing... **I had no idea that people drew a connection between the Ewan McGregor is Obi-Wan Kenobi [thing]
> and the woman being named Satine.** I didn't realize that at all. I
> called Henry Gilroy, who named Satine, and asked him, "Hey, were you
> aware of this?" And he said no, that he didn't really think about it.
> And I was like, "My gosh, do you know what people are saying all over
> the place about this trailer?" It had nothing to do with that. I guess
> it's just synergy? I don't know. It's very bizarre. **I still wanna
> question Gilroy about that, because I'm like, "Come on, really? I
> mean, out of all the names, really?" It's pretty weird, I'll give you
> that.***

Comment: Actually that's not what he said. He said that **he** was unaware of the connection, but he seems to suspect that Henry Gilroy may have chosen the name subconsciously.